# Unwanted padding in CollapsibleToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-design-library

i have the following code in my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="global.sti.attendance.SignUpActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsibleToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/colorful_background"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The scrolling works fine however there is unwanted padding inside my CollapsingToolbarLayout this is the result:

[image]

What seems to be the problem? Thanks!

PS: I already wrapped my layout inside coordinatorlayout and I dont know why stackoverflow editor doesnt recognized it when i pasted it in here.

Comment: You mean on the sides of the image?

Comment: @DeeV yes the spaces in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this on your Toolbar

```
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Comment: Still the same, i dont know if this has something to do with the image cause i have a blurred image though i used high res images.

Comment: Have you tried setting android:adjustViewBounds="false" on ImageView?

Comment: I've just tried your code but with a different image in the ImageView and for me it works fine (no margins)....maybe it's the image....have you tried setting a different image and see if the results are different?